# Selenium IEDriver accept download

Tags: python, selenium, webclient

How would I accept to save this download link with selenium and IEDriver? (This is already a iedriver page)[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to control the download pop-ups on browsers using selenium because browsers use native dialogs which cannot be controlled by JavaScript, so you need some alternate approaches.

Alternate approaches to get this working :

- Get your browser preconfigured. This means everytime you click on download of some file, your browser should directly download it without giving you options to open/save/cancel. This can be set in settings menu of all browsers.
- You can try something more harder, read this : [link](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/)

Note : I am assuming you are automating something here. And all automation tests have a @Before condition which you should ensure so that your test goes through. In your case, if you follow the first (& easy approach) I have given - it will be your @Before condition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well alright then, my fears are confirmed! Thanks I'll try the preconfiguration before anything else!